# Is that possible to apply style with server side data in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

One of my RN component rendered a data from external server. the data is wrapped with RN components.

like below

```
... 

<View>
 <Text>{this.props.db.greeting}</Text>
</View>
```

and DB is a simple object.

```
{ key: 1, greeting: 'Hello' }
```

What I want to do is, **without edit RN code**, applying styles to client side using server-side code.

I tried:

```
{ key: 1, greeting: '<Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Hello</Text>'}
{ key: 1, greeting: '{ <Text style={{color: 'red' }}>Hello</Text> }'}
{ key: 1, greeting: '{{ <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Hello</Text> }}'}
{ key: 1, greeting: '`<Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Hello</Text>`'}
```

I expected :

```
Hello(red)
```

But results were :

```
<Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Hello</Text>
```

everytime they treated as a string

Is that possible?, If so how can I do that?

Comment: You have to edit client-side to meet your purpose.

Comment: `greeting ` should be a function which should return jsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible unless you decide to modify your client side code. What you receive from the API is a string, you need to convert that into valid JSX inside your client side code.

You can refer to plugins like https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview which render raw HTML strings inside react native views, but in your case it will not be HTML but RN flavored template strings.

Alternatively I'd suggest re-structuring your API response to

```
{ key: 1, greetingText: 'Hello', greetingStyles: {color: 'red'}}
```

Now you can render on client side like this

```
... 

<View>
 <Text style={this.props.db.greetingStyles}>{this.props.db.greetingText}</Text>
</View>
```

This gives you more control over your `<Text>` nodes by allowing you to add default styles, event handlers etc.

If you are worried about having to deploy a new build for the application everytime you change anything related to `<Text>` nodes, you don't need to because using https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/ you can deploy JS only changes to your applications almost instantly :)

Comment: Thanks... I applied `htmlview` to client side, and it print html code well